# Custom linux kernel module: ".gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time"

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to load a barebones Linux device driver module, but I keep getting hit with this:

```sh
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module dummydriver.ko: Invalid module format
```

Google searches tell me that a common cause for this message is that the kernel versions are mismatched between the OS and what the developer used to compile the module. I'm running the correct kernel version as far as I can tell.

```sh
uname -r
6.5.6-76060506-generic
```

Driver code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init driver_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "bababooey :D");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit driver_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "bababooey :(");
}

module_init(driver_init);
module_exit(driver_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("dude");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("driver");
```

Makefile:

```make
obj-m = dummydriver.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Make output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.6-76060506-generic/build M=/home/david/Programming/dummydriver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.6-76060506-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/dummydriver.o
  MODPOST /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/dummydriver.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/dummydriver.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.6-76060506-generic'
```

I'm running Pop OS 22.04 if it matters. Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE**

Issue hasn't been solved yet. `dmesg` shows

```
module dummydriver: .gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time
```

At 0andriy's suggestion, I set up signage on the module, but secure boot isn't enabled so I don't think it matters anyway? Setting up proper signing didn't change anything, and the error still occurs.

Comment: You need more than just match the kernel version. The loadable module must have been linked with that specific kernel build.

Comment: What is output of `dmesg` after the failed attempt to `insmod`?

Comment: Check the output of `dmesg`. I think this problem can happen sometimes if the major version of the GCC compiler used to build the modules is different from the major version of GCC that was used to build the kernel, but check the output of `dmesg` to be sure.

Comment: dmesg says `module dummydriver: .gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time`

Any idea what I should do with this message?

Comment: Have you signed your module? The answer is “No”, because you haven’t possessed the private key, if kernel requires signature you won’t get any custom module to be loaded. I.o.w. always experiment in a virtual environment where you have a full control over the execution.

Comment: @0andriyis Interesting, haven't learned about this yet. Is this in response to my most recent comment or my post?

Comment: To the post. As it seems you are using distro's kernel.

Comment: @0andriy Ok, I signed the module and am still encountering the error. Also, I see your advice to use a virtual environment, but I'd really prefer to get it working on my machine; do you have any advice for that?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently encountered a similar problem. In my case, the driver was originally working properly, but it became unavailable after I modified the kernel compilation options. Displaying this error after insmod.

```
.gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel
```

So I recompiled the driver and updated it in the file system, and then there were no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I've had a similar problem while trying to compile a basic "Hello, World" module and could not find anyone with an answer that worked for me but ended up solving my own problem.

My Xubuntu 22.04 virtual machine was running 6.5.0-21-generic, as output by `uname -r`, but my `/lib/modules/` directory contained multiple subdirectories that did not match this version. I realized I had multiple packages installed on the vm named `linux-headers-xxxxxx` where `xxxxxx` corresponded to various other kernel versions.

I uninstalled all `linux-header-xxxxxx` packages, including the `linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic` that I was building my module against, then reinstalled the kernel headers I wanted to build against. I then recompiled and was able to successfully insert the module with `insmod`.